# Pass addl parameter to angularjs promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, angularjs-http

```
        var doLogin = function(username, password) {
            var request = $http({
                method: "get",
                url: 'api/login',
                params: {},
                data: {}
            });

            return request.then(success, error);
        }

        function success(response, username) { ... }
```

If I remove username as a parameter for success() method, response gets passed to success(), and everything works fine. For this specific instance, I need to also pass the username (passed into doLogin) to the http success callback function. However, the promise only takes the reference to the function. How do I pass the username to fn success()?

Comment: This looks odd to me. Shouldn't the doLogin function be exposed through a service and simply return a promise? Within the controller all your functions would then be able to close over the username or have it available in the promise chain.

Comment: I'm doing stuff to store data in the service (as opposed to rootScope), and then returning another promise with the data wrapped in an object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass an anonymous function as the success callback:

```
return request.then(function(data) {
    success(data, username);
}, error);
```